# Logical error in my jQuery Mobile script

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In this jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fRb9L/2/

When clicking on "Three" while viewing tab #1 will slide the right way to tab #3

But when I click on "One" while viewing tap #3 it will still slide in the same direction.  I want it to slide in the opposite direction.

Is the issue coming from this part?

```
if (!$(href).is(":visible"))
{
        var dirclass = reverse == true ? " reverse" : "";
```

Or this part?

```
$(this).removeClass(trans + " in"  + dirclass);
```

What part of this source code must be changed to solve that issue?  Thanks Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reverse` variable doesn't help to determine which direction should be chosen during click.

You should compare element that was selected before with element you are selecting.

Based on `href` string comparing it will look like:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRb9L/4/).

```
$(".tabBtn").on("click", function(){
    var selectedHref = $('.ui-btn-active').prop("href");
    selectedHref = selectedHref.substr(selectedHref.lastIndexOf("#"));
    $(".tabBtn").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
    $(this).addClass("ui-btn-active");
    var trans = $(this).data("transition");
    var href = $(this).prop("href");
    href = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#"));
    if (!$(href).is(":visible")){
        var dirclass = href < selectedHref ? " reverse" : "";
        ...
```

Based on HTML structure:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRb9L/5/).

```
$(".tabBtn").on("click", function(){
    var selected = $('.ui-btn-active');
    $(".tabBtn").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
    $(this).addClass("ui-btn-active");
    var trans = $(this).data("transition");
    var href = $(this).prop("href");
    href = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("#"));
    if (!$(href).is(":visible")){
        var dirclass = $(this).parent().nextAll().find(selected).length ? " reverse" : "";
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I like the one based on HTML structure more